# How is $R_iR_j$ defined in the definition of graded rings?

Tags: notation, graded-rings

In the definition of graded rings there is the condition $R_iR_j\subset R_{i+j}$, it involves the product of two subgroups $R_iR_j$.

How is the set $R_iR_j$ defined?

Edit: Is anyone aware of a textbook in which this is defined?

Comment: $AB=\{ab\mid a\in A,b\in B\}.$

Comment: @RandomSeed The $R_j$'s are not rings, only additive subgroups.

Comment: @AnneBauval By any chance do you know a textbook where the product of two subgroups $R_iR_j$ is defined?

Comment: When defining the product $R_iR_j$, you forget about the subgroup structure of $R_i$ and $R_j.$ My previous comment was only to correct your word "rings".

Comment: Sorry, I don't know such a textbook for the product, but I added a link in my answer for the sum (for which there are plenty of references). Btw, I find it unfair to modify your post after receiving appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer *before the post was modified, asking for a reference*.

The product of two subsets is defined exactly like the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition):
$$AB=\{ab\mid a\in A,b\in B\},$$
hence the condition $R_iR_j\subset R_{i+j}$ means that for every homogeneous elements $x,y\in R,$ the product $xy$ is homogeneous and
$$\deg(xy)=\deg x+\deg y.$$

Answer (score 0):

$R = \oplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}} R_i$ (as abelian groups), so there are natural inclusions $i_i : R_i \rightarrow R$. The condition is that if $a \in range(i_i), b \in range(i_j)$, then $ab \in range(i_{i+j})$